# javascript show loading panel without ajax call or service call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-spinner

I want to show loading spinner inside javascript function itself. without  setTimeout I have load spinner. can any one help me to sort out

```
//show progress bar   
$('.ajax-loading').show();

//very long loop or short loop
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   ------
 }
// hide progress bar
$('.ajax-loading').hide();
```

Comment: if you want simple css and javascript solution then i will give you but i dont know about kndro.ui.progress. ? it is selectore like $('.progress') in jquery

Comment: actuality you want delay without  setTimeout and ajax, right ?

Comment: yes I need without settimeout load the spinner.

Comment: Kevel, no problem yaar. I try with all loading panel. its not working. I modified the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. if you're trying it than it's a bad user experience. JavaScript does not work in that way because long running JavaScript synchronous jobs block the browser's UI (everything on Ui), including image animations.

And the bad news is a majority of browser crashes are caused by badly 
constructed JavaScript loops.

That's why no loading image will show during the execution of your loop.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64CRY/524/)

HTML:

```
<button class="k-button" id="progressStartButton" >Loading Start ......</button>
<div id="tabStripCompany">
                <ul>
                    <li class="k-state-active">Loading Example</li>

                </ul>
                <!-- Settings tab -->
                <div id="settingsTab" >
                    <div id="customerSettingsLoading" ></div>
                    <div id="customerSettings">


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div >
                    More stuff here...
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
kendo.ui.progress($("#customerSettings"), true);
setInterval(function(){
         kendo.ui.progress($("#customerSettings"), false);
    $("#progressStartButton").text("Loading End !")
}, 3000)

$("#tabStripCompany").kendoTabStrip();
```

CSS:

```
#customerSettings {
    position: relative;
}
#customerSettings{height:200px}
```

Comment: Thanks Shailendra.. here my requirement is to expand grid on client side its getting long time to expand so I try implement progress bar for user interface.